# Identifying the tail of a heavy tailed distribution

Tags: distributions, heavy-tailed

I have several distributions with a heavy right hand tail as shown below.

[image]

I am not interested in analyzing the tail of this distribution. Is there any official definition on where a tail begins on a heavy tailed distribution? If so is there an algorithm I can use to identify the tail?

Comment: There's no defined place where the 'tail' starts - or rather, there's certainly no general one that applies in all instances. You're free to define one for your case if there's a single definition that's relevant for your situation. What are you using the data to do? It sounds like you're planning to exclude data in the upper and or lower tail but that might not be the best way to [solve the underlying problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) that you're trying to use this on.

Answer (score 1):

The "tails" more specifically refers to the kurtosis of the distribution. For distributions like the one you show, where the skewness is the prominent feature, we describe the distribution as being skewed to the right. All distributions are two tailed, the right and the left, starting at some arbitrary threshold, usually the mode for unimodal distributions. For continuous distributions, both tails are infinitely long, so you can't really refer to one as the "long" one. For instance, in this heavily skewed distribution, you can't really refer to "the tail", there are two of them.
[image]

Tailedness is an abstract statistical quantity related to "the 4th moment". A normal distribution is generally thought of mesokurtic, i.e. having normal kurtosis, with kurtosis of 3. Anything less than 3 is described as platykurtic ("light tailed") and larger than 3 as leptokurtic ("heavy tailed"). Some people subtract 3 from kurtosis so that 0 is a normal value.

Tailedness is an ironic designation because distributions often have 2 tails. For instance, even though the exponential distribution is monotonic, it has two tails, one is very heavy and one is very light. There is no agreed upon, formal definition of where the "central" part of a distribution ends and where the "tails" begin.

Kurtosis is not to be confused with skewness, the 3rd moment which describes the lack of symmetry of a distribution. This seems to be the quantity you're interested in because it's the most apparent feature of the histogram you show.

There is no way to "analyze" a segment of a distribution. You may perhaps present some descriptive statistics, but it makes no sense without considering the entire distribution.

Comment: I don't think I agree with the statement in the first sentence; I don't think "the tail" generally does refer to kurtosis specifically (though the two are naturally related)

Comment: I agree with @Glen_b. In particular, the kurtosis measures something about *both* tails, not just the right or left side, and as a single number it doesn't provide much useful information.  The interpretation of a kurtosis greater than 3 is that there are some data further away from the middle than you would expect for a Normal distribution--but this is already obvious from the plot.  As far as "segments" of distributions go, there are very good ways to analyze them with mixture models or even a careful study of N-letter summaries.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that you are not interested in analyzing the "tail", you must have some idea what the tail is. So, you can use that idea to decide. There's no official definition.

I would, however, be *very* leery of doing this. You don't say what the variable is or what you are doing (you really should tell us) so there's no way to be too specific, but the tails are often very interesting and arbitrarily removing them is often a very bad idea.

In general, I would say that it is *sometimes* OK to remove a tail on *substantive* grounds (e.g. if you don't want to include people over a certain age or something) but that would not depend on the distribution but on what you are studying.